# Constant UUIDs for functional logging (design)

Tags: java, logging, uuid

I'm working on a issue regarding functional logging (log seen by non-developers). One requirement is adding a unique ID per log entry. This is such that the product managers can query on said ID and get all the associated log entries.
A (pseudo) code example is shown below:

```
if (something starts or happens here){
    //arguments: container id, service name, message, message uuid
    functionalLogService.addLog(container.getId(), this.SERVICE_NAME, "this happened", "124e3314-ffad-4b5d-be76-fc6b0f82aeea");
}
```

I have to do this quite often and I don't really like having random UUIDs hardcoded in loglines. The UUID is different for each log statement. One option is to leave it as is, which works, another is to create constants for each UUID, which seems overkill.

My question: is there any kind of design or "nice" way to do this?

**EDIT**

I've already had the idea of using:

```
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(message.getBytes()).toString();
```

But if at some point I want to change the message, the database will no longer be backwards compatible. So this option is out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have unique `container.getId()` and you know this id, you can create UUID with concatenate `container.getId()` and `this.SERVICE_NAME` and supplement with characters from generated [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). All you enteries would have unique id that start with  `container.getId()` and `this.SERVICE_NAME`.

In logs you may find specific log entry that start with `container.getId()` and `this.SERVICE_NAME`.

**Or**

Create class with `public static final` constants, with names that make sense, (`LogEntryConstants.java`) and use this constants in log entry. Also, if this acceptably, add to value of those constants some readable text that include maybe `this.SERVICE_NAME`, with this text you can simplify search by keyword(`this.SERVICE_NAME`) in logs. It's overkill, but you organize your code and get rid off hardcode right in the business logic, moving it to utilities class `LogEntryConstants`.

Comment: This was my initial idea as well, but containerId changes and the UUID for a specific log entry should stay constant, hence I cannot use this.

Answer (score 0):

Below code help you...
// creating UUID
      UUID uid = UUID.fromString("38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b96e4ef00d");

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/uuid_fromstring.htm